# Dual boot - Ubuntu partition resize results in grub terminal at startup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gparted, resize

I have dual boot with windows and Ubuntu. I wanted to resize my Ubuntu root so I shrinker one of the partition using the disk management in windows. I used gparted to move swap partition to the left and also my Ubuntu partition to the left. I regenerated the UUID. Now when I restart I get grub terminal. I followed few blogs and set the root, linux and initrd.img. Then I end up getting initramfs terminal saying 'No init found. Try passing init=bootarg'. Please help me with this issue

Comment: At what step in this process did your system start failing to boot?

Comment: After the 'No init found' in the initramfs terminal

Comment: Reboot takes me back to grub terminal

Comment: Not what I am asking. Did you make all those changes in one fell swoop and only after making all those changes tried to boot the system. In other words, did you try to boot the system at any point during the process.

Comment: Yes. After making all these changes I tried to boot the system.

Comment: So it could have broken at any one of these steps along the way. In future, consider testing out what you did after each major change.

Comment: I was able to get the bootup options menu. After selecting Ubuntu it says. Error no such device : jsh736. Disk hd0,gpt10 not found. But my actual Ubuntu is in hd1,gpt10.

Comment: Check UUIDs in fstab if you changed a UUID for swap or / (root). Is error after getting grub menu or before? I sometimes have to edit a boot and manually change a hd0 to h1 as plugging in a flash drive has drive order changed by  UEFI.

Comment: How do i do it? I've started ubuntu from a bootable pendrive. I'm not able to edit fstab.